# Use AlarmManger to call a specific method in Activity

Tags: android, service

How can I use **AlarmManager** to call a specific method of an Activity, in my case I need to stop a service by calling **KillMyServer** method of my Activity **2 hours** later from know.
I can't use **Timer** or **postDelayed**, because if an app goes to background Android may close it after a while, but AlarmManager will survive.

Comment: Why would you use an `Activity` to do this? The Android `Activity` class is designed to be a UI framework to allow direct interaction between the user and your app. It's not a general 'workhorse' class.

Answer (score 1):

why to use Alarm here? you can stop service by calling stopself() method on Service.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public static final String ACTION_START_TIMER = "com.sample.myapp.action.ACTION_START_TIMER";
    private TimerReceiver receiver;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        receiver = new TimerReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_START_TIMER);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    public void runKillTimer() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                stopSelf();
            }
        }, 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    private class TimerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            runKillTimer();
        }
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MyService.ACTION_START_TIMER);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because if an app goes to background Android may close it after a while, but AlarmManager will survive.

Comment: if app goes to background, Activities may be closed, but Service will survive until low memory situations (rare to be happened). so you can write Handler code in Service

Comment: I need to start kill timer right after app goes to background. How can I add this to service?

Comment: bind the service to the Activity and start kill timer in Service from onStop() of Activity

Comment: I did same, but kill timer won't survive for hours, but only about 1 hour!